# Biblioteca que leia texto e transforme em áudio

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou procurando alguma forma de implementar em meu sistema uma leitura automática com áudio. Funcionaria assim: O usuário faria uma pergunta (digitando) e o robozinho traria o resultado e 'leria'. Estou procurando algo em Node. Obrigado!

Comment: acho que vai ser MUITO difícil você achar isso.

Comment: tenta debugar o google tradutor.

Comment: Não acho muito difícil. Veja minha resposta e verá como fiz com o Google tradutor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho um colega de trabalho meu que utilizava o próprio `Google Tradutor`.

Veja como ele fazia em PHP:

```
$google_url = 'https://translate.google.com.br/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=%se&tl=pt&total=1&idx=0&textlen=5&tk=489936&client=t&prev=input&ttsspeed=0.24';

$text = urlencode('Meu nome é Wallace');

$url = sprintf($google_url, $text);

copy($url, 'meu_arquivo.mp3');
```

Esse código pode ser usado em qualquer outra linguagem (desde que ela aceite copiar arquivos remotos).

Veja que esse link funciona clicando [aqui](https://translate.google.com.br/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Meu+nome+%C3%A9+wallacee&tl=pt&total=1&idx=0&textlen=5&tk=489936&client=t&prev=input&ttsspeed=0.24)

## Atualização 06/01/2016

Acabo de descobrir que essas informações agora estão restritas, e que você só pode utilizar esse recurso através de uma chave da [API de Tradução](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs).

Parece-me também que é necessário [pagar pelo serviço](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing).

Answer (score 2):

Achei!

http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/
Muito interessante inclusive!